# How to install Window theme on Ubuntu without sudo privileges?

Tags: installation, gnome, windows, themes

I want to install a theme but, I need sudo! Im running Ubuntu 12.10 (Gnome 3). The theme in question is called "notxp theme". I don't have `sudo` privilege on my machine. Is there a way to install the theme despite that fact?

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about what doesn't work for you. What are you trying to do? Do you get any  error messages?

Comment: There's not much you can do without `sudo`. Please tell us if there are any issues with the `sudo` command first, we shall address it, and then you will be able to do what you're asking. There is virtually nothing you can do without `sudo`. It's like saying, "I'm going to eat an apple with my eye." It's not really possible. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, by the way.

Comment: Valid question for a workplace environment where the only person able to invoke sudo will likely never log on. =]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install themes system-wide, you would place them in `/usr/share/themes`, and icon themes would go in `/usr/share/icons`.  But since you don't have root access, you can't write to those directories.

However, you *can* write files to your home directory.  GTK themes can also be placed in `~/.themes` (and icons go in `~/.icons`).  For example, if your username is "peter" you would place files in `/home/peter/.themes`.

These folders may not exist, and even if they do, you almost certainly won't be able to see them by default.  Open your home folder and press [Ctrl]+[H] to display *dot files* - files and folders which start with a dot - these are hidden files under Linux.  Now you should see several dot files, including stuff like `.cache` and `.bash_logout`.  Don't remove these; they're there (and hidden!) for a reason.  Instead, just right-click and Create New Folder and call it `.themes`.

Since you didn't specify the particular theme you're working with, I can't guide you on the exact structure they should be copied into the folder with.  Feel free to edit your post, or look around in `/usr/share/themes` and mimic the structure with your own .themes directory.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Install [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).

Explore it. Now You can install any theme easily.

Comment: I need sudo for that